I'm looking for a word that describes someone who dislikes change/is afraid of it
I'm looking for a word that describes someone who dislikes change even while their current situation is less than favorable and keeps things even if they are old, worn and crumbling.
The closest thing I found was metathesiophobic, which is a phobia that causes people to avoid changing their circumstances due to being extremely afraid of the unknown (taken from google). Neophobic doesn't fit him either.
I'm making a characters bio, but I don't know if i want a phobia (in general) smack dab in the middle 
I'll try to answer any questions. Thanks in advance!

I don't think you will find the word. Dickens used a lot of description for the similar Miss Havisham in Great Expectations

"Conservative?" "All change is bad." - Faber

You could look up synonyms of hidebound.

What's wrong with neophobia? It's hard to answer if we don't know exactly what you want and don't want. But hidebound might be good.

change averse

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, a luddite is

a person who is opposed to the introduction of new working methods, especially new machines


someone who is against the introduction of new equipment, working methods, etc.:


We cannot be Luddites and pretend online publishing is not the future.

Wikipedia explains the origin as follows

Luddites were members of a 19th-century movement of English textile workers who opposed the use of certain types of automated machinery due to concerns regarding decreased pay for textile workers and a perceived reduction of output quality, and often destroyed the machines in organised raids. Members of the group referred to themselves as Luddites, self-described followers of "Ned Ludd", a mythical weaver whose name was used as a pseudonym in threatening letters to mill owners and government officials.

...

Over time, the term has been used to refer to those opposed to industrialisation, automation, computerisation, or new technologies or even progress in general.


Creating a character with such a nuanced trait is fascinating! While “metathesiophobic” and “neophobic” are close, they might not perfectly capture the essence you’re looking for. Here are a few suggestions that might fit better:
Words and Phrases
Tradition-bound:
This term describes someone who is strongly attached to traditions and resistant to change, even if their current situation isn’t ideal.
Conservative:
While often used in a political context, “conservative” can also describe someone who is resistant to change and prefers to stick with the familiar.
Intransigent:
This word means unwilling or refusing to change one’s views or to agree about something. It can imply a stubbornness to hold onto the old ways.
Stagnant:
Describes someone who is not advancing or developing; stuck in the same place, often due to a resistance to change.
Retentive:
This term can describe someone who holds onto things, both physically and mentally, even when they are no longer useful.
Nostalgic:
While typically associated with a longing for the past, it can also imply a reluctance to move forward and change.
Phrases
Change-averse:
Someone who actively avoids change.
Set in their ways:
Describes someone who is very fixed in their habits and routines.
Clinging to the past:
Someone who holds onto old ways and things, even when they are no longer beneficial.
Character Bio Integration
You can describe your character’s trait without labeling it as a phobia. For example:
“John is deeply tradition-bound, holding onto old, worn-out items and routines despite their crumbling state. His aversion to change keeps him anchored in the past, even when the present offers better opportunities.”
